# Unity3d - Color different parts of a sprite/image separately

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a simple sprite/ image in Unity3d. I would like to dynamically change the color of the leaves/ stalk/ petal separately.

What is the simplest way to go about it? Should I just create different objects and manipulate them separately, or is there a more efficient way to go about this?

(I am not looking for code, just a high level advice - e.g. use svg/ create a pre-fab with leaves/ stalk/ petals grouped together and just color each separately)

The reason I ask is, being new to Unity, I do not have the "grammar" to google something, but I would appreciate a quick pointer and should manage the rest.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you should create the leaves/stalk etc.. separately and paint them white except for their outline, once you're done you should import them into unity and then you can set any color you want for each part

Comment: Thank you - this is what I suspected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to save every part separately.
As I understand you will have more than one image to color. If so, I would suggest you to use scriptable objects to store images which are made of these separated sprites. Here's a video talking about basics of scriptable objects and how to use it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY

This is some basic code, how I imagine it would look for you to save the image:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Sprite Scriptable Object", menuName = "Sprite SO")]
public class ScriptObje : ScriptableObject {
    public string naming;
    public List<Sprite> parts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is as expected, but the scriptable objects will make it faster/ easier

Answer (score 0):

There is another option that would let you manipulate an svg: The way to do this would be to parse the SVG file to get a vector representation of the file (vector Scene), then you can change any properties before tessellation. For example:

```
string svg =
    @"<svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"" viewBox=""0 0 216 216"">
       <g>
           <polygon id=""Poly1"" points=""...""/>
       </g>
   </svg>";

// Import the SVG at runtime
var sceneInfo = SVGParser.ImportSVG(new StringReader(svg));
var shape = sceneInfo.NodeIDs["Poly1"].Shapes[0];
shape.Fill = new SolidFill() { Color = Color.red };

// Tessellate
var geoms = VectorUtils.TessellateScene(sceneInfo.Scene, tessOptions);

// Build a sprite
var sprite = VectorUtils.BuildSprite(geoms, 10.0f, VectorUtils.Alignment.Center, Vector2.zero, 128, true);
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
```

[source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-ui-svg-support-script.551254/page-2#post-4364425)